# How to get the methodname without hardcoding?

Tags: delphi

```
program Project37;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([vcPrivate,vcProtected,vcPublic, vcPublished])}

   type
      TBar = class
        procedure Test1; virtual;
      end;

      TFoo = class(TBar)
      end;


      procedure TBar.Test1;
      begin
        WriteLn(MethodName(@TBar.Test1)); //compiles, but does not show anything
        //WriteLn(MethodName(@Self.Test1)); //does not compile
      end;

var
  Foo: TBar;

begin
  Foo:= TFoo.Create;
  Foo.Test1;
  Foo.Free
  Foo:= TBar.Create;
  Foo.Test1;
  Foo.Free;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

If I run the program nothing shows.
How do I get `MethodName` to actually work?

I'm using XE7, but I doubt it's different in older versions.

Comment: `MethodName` hails from `System` and it seems it only works on members that are `published`. I'd guess your best bet is to make use of `System.Rtti`. Even then, I don't see what one could accomplish using Rtti: You're hardcoding your `@TBar.Test1` anyway, don't you? Looking at the stack is probably the only viable option, not Rtti.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful, the issue is refactoring. If I change the name, the string does not. That would be bad. And looking at the stack requires debuginfo, which I may not have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MethodName` requires the method to be published. Meet that requirements like so:

```
type
  TBar = class
  published
    procedure Test1; virtual;
  end;
```

If you want to get method names for members that are not published, use new style RTTI. Like so:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([vcPrivate,vcProtected,vcPublic, vcPublished])}

uses
  System.Rtti;

type
  TBar = class
  private
    procedure Test1;
  end;

procedure TBar.Test1;
begin
end;

var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  Method: TRttiMethod;

begin
  for Method in ctx.GetType(TBar).GetMethods do
    if Method.CodeAddress=@TBar.Test1 then
      Writeln(Method.Name);
end.
```

Naturally you could wrap this up into a function that would return a method name given a type and a code address.

Comment: Also note that the new Enhanced RTTI is significantly slower  than the traditional RTTI